# How do I properly set up my header cache on my website?

Tags: html, caching

After following several links, trying different solutions like adding

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="Thu, 31 Dec 2015 12:00:00 GMT">
```

to my header and trying other solutions, none of them seem to work. I really can't find a proper guide on where and how to add this properly. I started doing this after trying tome SEO (Search Engine Optimization) and getting this error.

> **Set a far future cache policy in 15 requests**
>
> Defining several days of cache retention for your static resources will reduce the load on your server.
>
> The expires header
>
> Some of your resources are using the Expires HTTP header to get an
>   effective caching policy: this is a best practice. However, you should
>   consider improving its configuration to make the most of the caching
>   mechanisms. Here is an example of the Expires HTTP header:
>
> Expires: Thu, 25 Dec 2014 20:00:00 GMT When you deploy a new version
>   of your website, remember to rename static resources that have been
>   modified. In fact, if you do not change their name, your users will
>   keep the resources stored in the cache, corresponding to the old
>   version. Then they may find themselves in an unstable version of your
>   page. This principle, called "versioning", is applied on DareBoost.com
>   for example. We integrate a version with the names of our files:
>
> dareboost.min.20140101.js See the Yahoo! guidelines on this subject.
>
> Settings
>
> We recommend setting the Expires HTTP header so that the mentioned
>   date is between 2 days and 1 year.
>
> This page contains 15 resources that do not have a far expiration
>   date:

Answer (score 0):

See Below:

```
 <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

More explanation you may find [here](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html) and [here](http://securityevaluators.com/knowledge/case_studies/caching/)

Comment: I assume the expires should be a date set in the future, right?
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Thu, 31 Dec 2015 12:00:00 GMT" />

   Actually neither solved the issue on Dareboosts scan of the page.